# Android Wi-Fi Direct: onPeersAvailable

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I'm developping a simple application based on WiFi Direct for Android that has to connect two devices. To do so I need to call to the función onPeersAvailable(myPeerListListener), but I don't know how.

My app has this two elements:

1-Main Activity:

```
package android.nacho.WifiDirect;



import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;

import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WifiDirect extends Activity {


    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    Channel mChannel;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_direct);


        //To register the BroadastReceiver
        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel =   mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null); //It was necessary to make a cast (Channel)
        mReceiver = new WiFiBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this); //, this);

        //Layout
        final Button btnScan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScan); 
        final TextView TextDebug=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextDebug);


        //To define the filter in the BroadcastReceiver
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);




        final OnClickListener ScanListener=new OnClickListener() //Sacado de TEstPsycologico
        {
            public void onClick(View v){



                TextDebug.setText("Se intentan buscar Peers");

                mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {


                    public void onSuccess() {

                        TextDebug.setText("Ha habido éxito buscando Peers");//DEBUG: Para ver si es posible encontrar Peers

                    }


                    public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {

                        TextDebug.setText("Algo ha salido mal buscando Peers"); //DEBUG: Para ver si pasó algo raro busando Peers
                    }
                });


                onPeersAvailable(myPeerListListener);

            }


        };

        btnScan.setOnClickListener(ScanListener);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_wifi_direct, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

   // unregister the broadcast receiver
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

}
```

2 Class BroadcastReceiver:

```
package android.nacho.WifiDirect;

import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.widget.Toast;



/**
 * A BroadcastReceiver that notifies of important Wi-Fi p2p events.
 */

public class WiFiBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private WifiDirect activity;
    private PeerListListener myPeerListListener;

    //For toast, add also context
    //private Context context;

    public WiFiBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel, WifiDirect activity){//, Context context) {

        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
       // this.context= context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();     


        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
             int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
             if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {

                //Toast.makeText(context, "Wi-Fi Direct is enable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             } else {

                //Toast.makeText(context, "Wi-Fi Direct is not enable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }      

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers

             // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
            // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
            // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
            if (manager != null) {
                 manager.requestPeers(channel, myPeerListListener);
                 manager.onPeersAvailable(myPeerListListener);

            }



        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
        }
    }
}
```

Until now my code should be able to detect peers around the device running the app, which ID should be stored in the variable **myPeerListListener**. All this take place in the second intend of the BroadcastReceiver method called OnReceiv(), by calling:

```
 manager.requestPeers(channel, myPeerListListener);
```

Now I want to manipulate that list. So following the API information it should be calling requestPeers, you can see the API on here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

*Section **Discovering Peers**

So what I have tried was to write below a call to:

```
manager.onPeersAvailable(myPeerListListener);
```

but I get this error:

**The method onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener) is undefined for the type WifiP2pManager**

Could anyone tell me how could I send the PeerListListener to the main activity properly?

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should implement the onPeersAvailable method inside the PeerListListener.

Please see http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html for more information.

Answer (score 15):

[dtheo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1805018/dtheo) has answered and point to the nice Android tutorial about this topic. I will just make changes on the OP's code to show how to achieve the requested functions.

According to the official Android guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#fetch), the wifip2p discovery api should be used in this way:

In your MainActivity class:

```java
mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
    public void onSuccess() {
        TextDebug.setText("Ha habido éxito buscando Peers");
    }

    public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
        TextDebug.setText("Algo ha salido mal buscando Peers");
    }
});

// ############# DELETE THE FOLLOWING LINE #############
onPeersAvailable(myPeerListListener); // <<<<<<< DELETE THIS LINE
```

And in your BroadcastReceiver class, do the following instead:

```java
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...    
    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        ...
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.requestPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
                Log.d(TAG,String.format("PeerListListener: %d peers available, updating device list", peers.getDeviceList().size()));

                // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
                // YOU CAN GET ACCESS TO ALL THE DEVICES YOU FOUND FROM peers OBJECT

            }
        });
        }
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Respond to new connection or disconnections
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

dtheo has answered the question.

I would just like to add a small side-note: For Wi-Fi Direct, both devices needs to be scanning at the same time to discover each other. There is also a scanning time-out which means that discoverability could be lost after some time.